# comparing numeric ASCII codes instead of character constants? And using fewer compares to find brackets?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
cmp     s1,'('
je      truth

cmp     s1,')'
je      truth

cmp     s1,'['
je      truth

cmp     s1,']'
je      truth

cmp     s1,'{'
je      truth     

cmp     s1,'}'
je      truth

jne     false
```

I want to ask how can I use ASCII code to compare input symbols with code of symbol instead of e.g. '{'. 
And if I can reduce amount of compares.

Comment: _"how can I use ASCII code to compare input symbols with code of symbol instead of e.g. '{'"_ Why would you want to do that? It would just make the code less readable. You could have a string `"()[]{}"` and search it with `repne scasb` to see if the current character matches any of the characters in that string.

Comment: We have assignment only with cmp and je jne
So I must use only such ways,but I need to compare with ASCII code,but I dont know how,professor didnt say that at all
We didnt even reach repne a.o. only in theory

Comment: _"I need to compare with ASCII code,but I dont know"_ You look up the characters in an ASCII table. But the assembler is already doing that for you (it will replace character literals with their ASCII codes).

Comment: thank you for answer,I have already did it with ASCII code,you're right,it's nosense,but it's moldavian educational system,so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASCII codes for **()[]{}** are 40, 41, 91, 93, 123, and 125.
Because these numbers lie scattered there's not much you can do to reduce the amount of compares.

From your comment I understand you're somewhat restricted to only use `cmp` but this should not hold you back in writing a better version of your code.
It's possible to shorten the 6 compares by using the AL register:

```
mov     al, s1
cmp     al, 40   ;'('
je      truth
cmp     al, 41   ;')'
je      truth
cmp     al, 91   ;'['
je      truth
cmp     al, 93   ;']'
je      truth
cmp     al, 123  ;'{'
je      truth     
cmp     al, 125  ;'}'
je      truth
jne     false
```

Not only is this the more usual way to write a series of compares, it also reduces your program size from 44 bytes down to 29 bytes which by all means is spectacular.

Comment: Yes, this is better by byte count, but OP asked how to minimize the number of comparisions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look up the character in a vector:

```
BracketMask equ 1
  mov    eax, s1
  test   ClassifyCharacter[eax], BracketMask
  jne    truth
false:
```

with a 128 byte lookup table:

```
  ClassifyCharacter  db   0,0,0,....,BracketMask,0,...,BracketMask,0,...,0  ; BracketMask values at offsets x40, x41, x91, x93, x123, and x125
```

This costs 2 memory reads and 3 machine instructions...

You can use this table for other character classifications, too, by defining additional bit masks and filling the the proper bits in the table.  One often wants to test for (sets of) digit characters,  upper and lower case letters,  crazy control characters (not CR, not LF) including Rubout, etc.    You have 8 bits per byte, so you can define 8 useful classes.

I use this trick in high-performance lexers for compilers.   Use direct compares if you only want to match a specific character; use the lookup table for any set.